# Is there any way to play inline [videos , youtube,flash] in phonegap?

Tags: android, html, plugins, cordova, inline

I want to embed inline videos to my android phonegap application (similar to video tag in html5) ,i do not need a fullscreen choice which leave my page.

so, is there any solution/plugin to embed inline videos or swf files? or phonegap does not support that and i  should stop searching ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this](https://github.com/macdonst/VideoPlayer) plugin to facilitate the same. I have used it and it works with a charm !